# Duvida Códificação (Charset) SoapClient Laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel, soap, soapclient

Gostaria de entender o motivo desta diferença numa consulta usando o *SOAP*:

- Numa aplicação a consulta do SOAP retorna-me uma `string` no formato **ASCII**, com caracteres especiais de forma de `??` como por exemplo:

> Apresenta??o do programa. Integra??o do professor e alunos. Evolu??o da Adm. da Produ??o e Operadores: O surgimento e o mundo da Adm. da Produ??o; Desenvolvimento hist?rico. ◀

Existe uma outra aplicação que utiliza essa mesma consulta SOAP, porém a `string` é retornada no formato **UTF-8**, com todos os caracteres especiais formatados.

A duvida é: porque noutra aplicação, que utiliza a mesma consulta SOAP, mesmos parâmetros, mesmo XML de consulta, um retorna-me em **ASCII** - a forma errada - e a outra retorna em **UTF-8** - forma correta?